# Computation of $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{x^2 \sin{x}}{1 - 2a\cos{x} + a^2}$

Tags: integration, fourier-series

How to compute the following integral. $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{x^2 \sin{x}}{1 - 2a\cos{x} + a^2}dx$$

I have got idea to transform a part of function in Fourier series and I obtained $$ \frac1a \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^n\int_0^{2\pi}x^2\sin(nx)dx = \frac{4\pi^2 \ln(1-a)}{a}, \: |a|< 1$$
**SOLVED**

Comment: did you try $f(x)=f(a+b-x)$

Comment: 1) What is your range of $a$? $a\neq 1$? 2) Where did you get your $b$ from in your approach. The answer cannot include a $b$...

Comment: I think it is an almost right approach. Assume that $|a| < 1.$ Expand $\dfrac{1}{a-e^{ix}}$ in a geometric series and observe that ${\rm Im}\dfrac{x^2}{a-e^{ix}} = \dfrac{x^2\sin x}{1-2a\cos x +a^2}$. In this case the value of the integral will be $4\pi^2\dfrac{\ln(1-a)}{a}.$ If $|a|>1$ you have to make some modifications.

Comment: For $|a|>1$ I would suggest to note that $I(a)=I(1/a)/a^2$.

Comment: look : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312096/evaluate-int-02-pi-frac-cos-2x1-2a-cos-xa2-with-a21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\mbox{Integrand} = {x^{2}\sin\pars{x} \over 1 - 2a\cos\pars{x} + a^{2}}}$.
$$
\substack{Integrand\\ Behaviour}:\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\ds{\mrm{As}\ a \to -1\,,\ \sim {1 \over 2}\,{x^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over 1 + \cos\pars{x}} =
{1 \over 4}\,{x^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over \cos^{2}\pars{x/2}} =
x^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{x \over 2}}
\\[3mm]
\ds{\mrm{As}\ a \to \phantom{-\,}1\,,\ \sim {1 \over 2}\,{x^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over
1 - \cos\pars{x}} =
{1 \over 4}\,{x^{2}\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over \sin^{2}\pars{x/2}} =
x^{2}\cos^{2}\pars{x \over 2}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

- As $\ds{a \to -1}$, the integrand has an integrable singularity at
  $\ds{x = \pi}$.
- As $\ds{a \to +1}$, the integrand has an integrable singularity at
  $\ds{x = 0}$ and at $\ds{x = 2\pi}$.

> With $\ds{a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{1}}$:

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2\pi}{x^{2}\sin\pars{x} \over 1 - 2a\cos\pars{x} + a^{2}}
\,\dd x =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{\pars{x^{2} + 2\pi x + \pi^{2}}\bracks{-\sin\pars{x}} \over
1 + 2a\cos\pars{x} + a^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-4\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\sin\pars{x} \over
1 + 2a\cos\pars{x} + a^{2}}\,\dd x
 =
-4\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\sin\pars{x} \over
\pars{a + \expo{\ic x}}\pars{a + \expo{-\ic x}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-4\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}x\sin\pars{x}\,
\pars{{1 \over a + \expo{-\ic x}} - {1 \over a + \expo{\ic x}}}
\,{1 \over \expo{\ic x} - \expo{-\ic x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
4\pi\int_{0}^{\pi}x\sin\pars{x}
\pars{{1 \over a + \expo{\ic x}} - {1 \over a + \expo{-\ic x}}}
{1 \over 2\ic\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x =
4\pi\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over a + \expo{\ic x}}\,\dd x
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large \verts{a} < 1}.$
\begin{align}
\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over a + \expo{\ic x}}\,\dd x & =
\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}{x\expo{-\ic x} \over 1 + a\expo{-\ic x}}\,\dd x =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-a}^{n}\
\overbrace{\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}x\expo{-\pars{n + 1}\ic x}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{{\pars{-1}^{n + 1} \over n + 1}}\,\pi}
\\[5mm] & =
-\pi\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{a^{n} \over n + 1} =
-\,{\pi \over a}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{a^{n} \over n} =
\bbx{\pi\,{\ln\pars{1 - a} \over a}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large\verts{a} > 1}.$
\begin{align}
\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over a + \expo{\ic x}}\,\dd x & =
{1 \over a}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over 1 + \pars{1/a}\expo{\ic x}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over a}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}
{x\expo{-\ic x} \over \pars{1/a} + \expo{-\ic x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over a^{2}}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over \pars{1/a} + \expo{-\ic x}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over a^{2}}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi}{x \over \pars{1/a} + \expo{\ic x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over a^{2}}\,\pi\,{\ln\pars{1 - 1/a} \over 1/a} =
\pi\,{\ln\pars{1 - 1/a} \over a}\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
Here, I used, the previous result, \eqref{2}.

> With \eqref{1}, \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}:

$$
\left.\int_{0}^{2\pi}{x^{2}\sin\pars{x} \over 1 - 2a\cos\pars{x} + a^{2}}
\,\dd x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ \in\ \mathbb{R}\setminus\braces{-1}} =
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{4\pi^{2}\,{\ln\pars{1 - a} \over a}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{\verts{a} < 1}
\\[2mm]
\ds{4\pi^{2}\,{\ln\pars{1 - 1/a} \over a}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{\verts{a} > 1}
\end{array}\right.
$$

> The cases $\ds{a \to 0}$ and $\ds{a \to -1}$ are given by $\ds{-4\pi^{2}}$ and
>   $\ds{-4\pi^{2}\ln\pars{2}}$, respectively. The integral diverges logarithmically when $\ds{a \to 1}$ $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{as}\ 4\pi^{2}\ln\pars{1 - a}~}}$.

---

The following picture is a plot for $\ds{a \in \pars{-4,4}\setminus\braces{1}}$:
[image]

Comment: Running an `NIntegrate` in Mathematica, and comparing, it looks like the answer of @JanG in the comments is the correct one. I guess that you have a sign error somewhere. (Perhaps in the first part)

Comment: @mickep Thanks. I'll check everything. I'm loosing my confident in $\texttt{Mathematica}$ somehow.

Comment: Well, in your case $|a|<1$, what you really get (there was a $(-1)^{n+1}$ missing in the calculation of the integral) is $$-\pi\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a^n}{n+1}=\pi\frac{\ln(1-a)}{a}.$$ This seems to be it. Now it is the same as JanG and Mathematica get.

Comment: @mickep Fixed. Thanks. I evaluated that integral with $\texttt{Mathematica}$. Then, I $\texttt{Expand}$ed the $\texttt{Numerator}$. Now, I see that  $\texttt{Mathematica}$ didn't include the prefactor $\left(\,-1\,\right)^{n + 1}$ when the  $\texttt{Numerator}$ was expanded. Thanks a lot: You really spent your time in my answer.