Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1+\cos(3t)}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}dt = \frac{\pi(a^2-a+1)}{1-a} \text{for}\ 0<a<1$
My integral follows:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+\cos(3t)}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}dt
=\frac{\pi(a^2-a+1)}{1-a},\quad 0<a<1.$$
I tried to expand the integral and already found when $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}dt$. For the cosine part, parametrize using $z = e^{it}$ and identify the poles, which are $z=a$ and $z=0$. However, my calculations don’t add up, and I’m not exactly sure which closed curve to use since with $|z|=1$, I don’t get the residue of
$f$ at 0 as the second derivative.
The theory I used was:
Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ open and connected, $f: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $a$ in $U$ a pole of order $k$ of $f$, then $$Res(f,a)=\frac{g^{(k-1)}(a)}{(k-1)!}.
$$
And
Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ open and connected, $f: U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $a$ a simple pole of $f$ then
$$Res(f,a) = \lim_{z \to a}(z-a)f(z).$$
Help!!!

Consider $I(0)+I(3)$, where
$$I(n)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\cos nt}{1-2a\cos t+a^2}dt = \frac{2\pi a^n}{1-a^2} $$

You can refer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312096/evaluate-int-02-pi-frac-cos-2x1-2a-cos-xa2-with-a21?noredirect=1

@
Claude Leibovici
Can you offer a simple method without complex analysis? Thanks.

For the cosine part, it should be $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos3t}{1-2a\cos t+a^{2}}dt = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+e^{6it}}{\left(1+a^{2}\right)e^{3it}-ae^{2it}\left(1+e^{2it}\right)}dt = \frac{1}{2i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1+z^{6}}{\left(1+a^{2}\right)z^{3}-az^{2}\left(1+z^{2}\right)}\frac{1}{z}dz$. If you use the substitution $z = e^{it}$ where $t \in [0, 2\pi]$, then you have to use the circle with radius $1$ because $e^{it}$ has a radius of 1 and forms a closed circle when $t$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$. There is a third-order pole at$z=0$ so you use the first theorem you listed in the...

(continued) post above. There is a first-order pole at $z=a$ and $z=1/a$, but since $1/a > |e^{it}|$ and $a < |e^{it}|$, you calculate the pole at $z=a$ because of the Residue Theorem. Despite all this, there is no need to split the integral into two parts, but rather you can use complex analysis directly.

There is no need to split up the two parts, with $z=e^{it}$
$$\frac{1+\cos3t}{1-2a\cos t+a^2}dt=\frac{(z^3 + 1)^2}{2 iz^3 (z - a) (1 - a z)}dz$$
The residue at $z=1/a$ is outside the contour, so adding the $z=0$ (taking the second derivative as you suggest, but don't forget to divide by 2: $\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} f(z)/z^3 = f''(0)/2!$) and $z=a$ residues you get (let me know if you need help with the missing steps)
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1+\cos3t}{1-2a\cos t+a^2}dt = 2\pi\frac{a^2-a+1}{1-a}$$
differing from the given answer by a factor of 2.

$$I=\int \frac{1+\cos(3t)}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}\,dt =\int \frac{4 \left(1-3
   x^2\right)^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3 \big( (1+a)^2\, x^2+(1-a)^2 \big)}\,dx$$
$$k=\left(\frac {1-a}{1+a}\right)^2\quad \implies \quad 
I=\frac 4 {(1+a)^2}\int \frac{ \left(1-3
   x^2\right)^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3 \big(  x^2+k \big)}\,dx$$
$$\frac{ \left(1-3
   x^2\right)^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3 \big(  x^2+k \big)}=\frac{9 k^2+6 k+1}{(k-1)^3 \left(x^2+1\right)}-\frac{9 k^2+6 k+1}{(k-1)^3
   \left(x^2+k\right)}-$$ $$\frac{8 (3 k-1)}{(k-1)^2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2}+\frac{16}{(k-1) \left(x^2+1\right)^3}$$ seems to be simple
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1+\cos(3t)}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}\,dt =2\int_0^{\pi} \frac{1+\cos(3t)}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}\,dt$$
As a result for the integration over $x$ from $0$ to $\infty$
$$I=2\times\frac 4 {(1+a)^2} \frac{\pi  (3 k+1)}{2 \left(\sqrt{k}+1\right)^3 \sqrt{k}}=\frac{2\pi  \left(a^2-a+1\right)}{1-a}$$
Edit
If $n$ is an integer, the same procedure leads to
$$J_n=\int_0^{2\pi}  \frac{1+\cos(nt)}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}\,dt =2\pi\, \frac{1+a^n}{1-a^2}$$

Nice idea with heavy computation!

Note
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+\cos(nt)}{1-2a\cos(t)+a^2}dt=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+\cos(nt)}{|e^{it}-a|^2}dt=\Re\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+e^{nit}}{|e^{it}-a|^2}dt=\Re\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1+e^{nit}}{(e^{it}-a)(e^{-it}-a)}dt=\Re\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{(1+e^{nit})e^{it}}{(e^{it}-a)(1-ae^{it})}dt\overset{z=e^{it}}=\Re\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(1+z^n)z}{(z-a)(1-az)}\frac{dz}{iz}=\Re\frac1i\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1+z^n}{(z-a)(1-az)}dz=\Re\frac1i\cdot2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\bigg(\frac{1+z^n}{(z-a)(1-az)},z=a\bigg)=\Re\bigg(2\pi\cdot\frac{1+a^3}{1-a^2}\bigg)=\frac{2\pi(1+a^n)}{1-a^2}.$$

Let $z=e^{xi}$, then $$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\Re\left[\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1+z^n}{1-a\left(z+z^{-1}\right)+a^2} \cdot \frac{d z}{i z} \right] \\
& =\Re\left[i \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{z^n+1}{(a z-1)(z-a)} d z\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $0<a<1$, $ \frac{z^n+1}{(a z-1)(z-a)} $ has only one pole at $z=a$ and hence $$
\boxed{I =\Re\left[i \cdot 2 \pi i \lim _{z \rightarrow a} \frac{z^n+1}{a z-1}\right] =2 \pi \cdot \frac{a^n+1}{1-a^2}}
$$
